# RegEx for N digits always starting with 2

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to validate these rules:

> 1)Only numbers
>
> 2)Must have 13 digits
>
> 3)Always start with number 2
>
> 4)May have dots after the first 8 digits, 2 digits and before last
>   digit like:
>
> ```
> (XXXXXXXX.XX.XX.X)
> ```

Example:

```
2437313600001 - 23610579.00.03.1
```

So far I have this

```
^([0-9]-?){13}$
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is wrong about your regex? In which cases does it fail? False positives? False negatives?

Comment: The regex you show has a `-` which I cannot find in the stated rules.

Comment: As per your rules I'd rather think of [`^2\d{7}\.?\d{2}\.?\d{2}\.?\d$`](https://regex101.com/r/0jvwct/1) or to only allow 5 digits or the desired pattern after first 8 digits: [`^2\d{7}(?:\d{5}|\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d)$`](https://regex101.com/r/0jvwct/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^2\d{7}(?:\.?\d){5}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `2` - Start first character with `2` only
- `\d{7}` - Next seven characters can be any digits
- `(?:\.?\d){5}` - Next five characters can be any digits but they can be preceded by an optional dot before them
- `$` - End of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WOypwb/1/)**